# How to convert .arf file into .mp4 or any other format in linux

Tags: webex

How to convert .arf file into .mp4 or any other playable format? I went through [this link](http://blog.ricardoamaro.com/content/how-watch-arf-webex-files-your-linux-desktop)

This was fine until I got this:

> Converting {path to arf} to {destination} 
>   Retrieving video data, fps=4...

At the destination no converted file appeared.

Comment: same thing happened.